# Facebook Page Access_token for reviews and ratings

Tags: facebook-access-token

I am working on a project where I need to get the reviews and ratings from Facebook pages I do not administer (admin is unknown). How can I get the page access (access_token) for reviews and ratings in our Android project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get access to the reviews and ratings by using a Page Token, so there is no way to get reviews and ratings for a Facebook Page you don´t own. You can only get a Page Token for Pages you do own, by authorizing a user with `manage_pages`.

Comment: Thanks @luschn but our requirement is to get the reviews and ratings  for all business pages available on facebook in our android application.could any one please help me with this..?

Comment: i know what the requirement is, but it is not possible.

Comment: Is there any other way to accomplish this task (requirement) ? Any help will be appreciable it is very urgent.

Comment: no, there is no other way. some things just are not possible, i am sorry.

Comment: What about the google+ pages ? Could i get reviews and ratings from google+ pages i do not administer ? How to get google+ pages review in android..?

Comment: short answer: yes. the long answer would be off topic and should be in a new thread.

Comment: could you please make it brief... i have to implement it in my project..at least provide the procedure ...

Comment: as i said, it is off topic. you are asking something completely different, and dealing with the google api is not something for a brief moment. if you need someone to do the work for you, just hire someone. it´s all in the google api docs, don´t be lazy ;)